# Intellij: Can I define a post "Stop Debugging" action (method call, log line, etc.)?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a cleanup method on my Java project.
I would like to have my cleanup method triggered once I push the "Stop Debugging" while debugging my Java code on IntelliJ.
Is it possible?
I would settle even with some writings to log.

Comment: Did you try the shutdown hook? See https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-shutdown-hooks.

Comment: @duffymo My cleanup deletes videos I upload to S3. I know about the videos only on startup so searching for orphaned videos every time I start my program is not applicable.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Yes, looks good! If you'd like to, you may add it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JVM shutdown hook will help:

```
Thread printingHook = new Thread(() -> System.out.println("In the middle of a shutdown"));
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(printingHook);
```

[See this document](https://www.baeldung.com/jvm-shutdown-hooks) for more details.